# Is a log-normal random variable plus a positive constant still log-normal?

Tags: statistics, logarithms, random-variables

> Let $Y$ be a log-normal random variable and let $c > 0$ be a constant. Is it true that $c + Y$ is log-normal?

Any suggestion or answer would be very helpful.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to pose a detailed problem you want help with.  Using the title alone to carry this burden invites confusion on the part of interested Readers.  See [ask] and use the space allowed to explain your context for the Question, e.g. why is it interesting? what approach did you attempt? where did you encounter a difficulty?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299482/is-cy-lognormal

Answer (score 4):

Notice that the support of a log-normal distribution is $(0, \infty)$.

Hence $c+Y$ can't be a lognormal.